# ¿Cómo puedo enlazar mi drawer layout con un hamburger button y acceder a los botones de la derecha de un Floating Search View?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawerlayout, searchview

Soy un novato en esto, pero estoy tratando de implementar un Search View flotante como el de la app de Google Maps, pero no encuentro la forma de enlazar su hamburger button a mi drawer layout, la página del Searh View que estoy usando es el siguiente: [Floating Search View](https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview)

También no he podido agregar listeners a los botones de la derecha del Search View.

> El listener de los clicks al hamburger button

```
 mSearchView.setOnLeftMenuClickListener(
    new FloatingSearchView.OnLeftMenuClickListener() { ...} );
```

> Esto hace que se conecte al hamburger button

```
mSearchView.attachNavigationDrawerToMenuButton(mDrawerLayout);
```

> Esta es la parte que hace funcionar los botones de la derecha

```
   mSearchView.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new FloatingSearchView.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onMenuItemSelected(MenuItem item) {                  
            
      }
   });
```

Ahí hay ejemplos de cómo ponerlos, pero siento que son para personas más avanzadas en cuestión de programación en android.

Por favor ayúdenme, llevo semanas buscando y tratando de implementarlo, pero no he tenido éxito.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sergio, estás en SO en **español** / You are in SO in **Spanish**.

Comment: Perdón, decía que estoy tratando de implementar un Floating Action Button que quiero poner en mi app, pero es de una librería de github y siento que sus ejemplos son para gente que ya sabe mucho, entonces quería una idea de cómo enlazar el hamburger button a mi drawer layout y también los botones como por ejemplo el del micrófono y la ubicación.

Comment: Sergio, por favor edita tu pregunta para traducirla al español además de agregar el código relevante. Si no la cierran por el idioma la cerrarán por falta de información

Comment: en la carpeta menu estan los "iconos" de la barra y debes pasarle al xml el nombre del archivo de la siguiente forma: app:floatingSearch_menu="@menu/menu_main" y para programar su accion lo haces asi:   mSearchView.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new FloatingSearchView.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onActionMenuItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() ==R.id.action_voice_rec){
     
    }
   }

  });

Comment: Es que el problema es que no sé dónde poner lo de programar sus acciones, intenté poniéndolo en onCreate(), afuera de todo, en onMapReady(), en todos lados y siempre me marca setOnMenuItemClickListener en rojo

Comment: en el oncreate, debes colocarlo, y en el xml de la carpeta menu, creas un identificador , en el caso del que te mande era action_voice_rec, algo asi deberia ser xml http://prntscr.com/g0bobm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disculpen por no compartir la respuesta antes, pero quedó resuelta en el foro en inglés, por [j2ko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2751535/j2ko).

Aquí está el ejemplo completo:

`AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.j2ko.webviewapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".FloatingSearchActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

`FloatingSearchActivity` layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.j2ko.webviewapp.FloatingSearchActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_floating_search">

        <com.arlib.floatingsearchview.FloatingSearchView
            android:id="@+id/floating_search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:floatingSearch_searchBarMarginLeft="10dp"
            app:floatingSearch_searchBarMarginTop="10dp"
            app:floatingSearch_searchBarMarginRight="10dp"
            app:floatingSearch_searchHint="Search..."
            app:floatingSearch_suggestionsListAnimDuration="250"
            app:floatingSearch_showSearchKey="false"
            app:floatingSearch_leftActionMode="showHamburger"
            app:floatingSearch_close_search_on_keyboard_dismiss="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#c46ec4">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Drower item 1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Drower item 2"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Drower item 3"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Y finalmente `FloatingSearchActivity` :

```
package com.j2ko.webviewapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.arlib.floatingsearchview.FloatingSearchView;
import com.arlib.floatingsearchview.suggestions.model.SearchSuggestion;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FloatingSearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FloatingSearchView mSearchView;
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    //Datos ejemplo para sugerencias de búsqueda
    private static final List<String> SOME_HARDCODED_DATA;
    static {
        SOME_HARDCODED_DATA = new ArrayList<>();
        SOME_HARDCODED_DATA.add("One");
        SOME_HARDCODED_DATA.add("Two");
        SOME_HARDCODED_DATA.add("Three");
        SOME_HARDCODED_DATA.add("Four");
    }

    //Esto es sólo para ilustrar cómo completar sugerencias de búsqueda
    private static class SimpleSuggestions implements SearchSuggestion {
        private final String mData;
        public SimpleSuggestions(String string) {
            mData = string;
        }
        @Override
        public String getBody() {
            return mData;
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(mData);
        }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<SimpleSuggestions> CREATOR
                = new Parcelable.Creator<SimpleSuggestions>() {
            public SimpleSuggestions createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new SimpleSuggestions(in);
            }

            public SimpleSuggestions[] newArray(int size) {
                return new SimpleSuggestions[size];
            }
        };

        private SimpleSuggestions(Parcel in) {
            mData = in.readString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_floating_search);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mSearchView = (FloatingSearchView) findViewById(R.id.floating_search_view);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryChangeListener(new FloatingSearchView.OnQueryChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSearchTextChanged(String oldQuery, final String newQuery) {
                List<SearchSuggestion> list = new ArrayList<SearchSuggestion>();
                //Emulando la búsqueda con datos de ejemplo
                for (String item : SOME_HARDCODED_DATA) {
                    if (item.contains(newQuery)) {
                        list.add(new SimpleSuggestions(item));
                    }
                }
                mSearchView.swapSuggestions(list);
            }
        });
        //ahora buscar el view controlando el drawer abrirlo/cerrarlo
        mSearchView.attachNavigationDrawerToMenuButton(mDrawerLayout);
    }

}
```

El resultado es el siguiente :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les comparto el enlace de la respuesta original:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45315069/i-cant-put-a-listener-to-hamburger-button-and-the-right-buttons-clicks-in-a-flo

Gracias por su ayuda y comentarios.

Comment: Deberías copiar y pegar aqui la respuesta que recibiste en [so] para que futuros usuarios con el mismo problema tengan aqui mismo la respuesta sin tener que visitar ningun enlace.